# Etiquetas de Cierres Extraviadas en codigo fuente

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, sublimetext3

Empece a usar CodeFormatter En sublimetext3 para ordenar el codigo. utiliza un estilo llamado psr2.

La cuestión es que me genera etiquetas de cierres para link, meta o br, que normalmente no las ponía.

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
            <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
                <!-- CSRF Token -->
                <meta content="bRkaytOFL85XDRnXUu9rF41lkAnMpqLO6wGb7pAq" name="csrf-token">
                    <title>
                        Crear Articulo | Panel de Administración
                    </title>
                    <link href="http://emap.com.ar/css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
                        <link href="http://emap.com.ar/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                            <link href="http://emap.com.ar/plugins/chosen/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                <link href="http://emap.com.ar/plugins/sceditor/themes/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                    <link href="http://emap.com.ar/plugins/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                        <link href="http://emap.com.ar/css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                        </link>
                                    </link>
                                </link>
                            </link>
                        </link>
                    </link>
                </meta>
            </meta>
        </meta>
    </meta>
</head>
```

En principio queda mas prolijo. Pero se me ocurrió ver el código fuente desde el navegador. y Todas esas etiquetas de cierre las coloca en rojo y identifica como etiquetas de cierre extraviadas. probando veo q no me da ningun problema.

Pero quisiera saber si esto puede saber si este tipo normalizacion esta bien o vuelvo hacia atras o si me acarrear algun problema mas adelante

Comment: No conozco el plugin, pero ¿no hay forma de cambiar el schema de X(HT)ML a HTML? Quizás vale la pena probar si reconoce el DTD poniendo `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` al principio del documento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la especificación de HTML5, los elementos "void" como `<meta>`, `<link>` y `<br>` en este caso, NO deben llevar etiqueta de cierre:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-0

> Void elements:
>
> area, base, **br**, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, **link, meta**, param, source, track, wbr
>
> Void elements only have a start tag; **end tags must not be specified for void elements**.

No conozco dicho plugin, pero si puedes desactivar el procesamiento del HTML sería lo mejor, o al menos las etiquetas del head.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <!-- CSRF Token -->
  <meta content="bRkaytOFL85XDRnXUu9rF41lkAnMpqLO6wGb7pAq" name="csrf-token">
  <title>Crear Articulo | Panel de Administración</title>
  <link href="http://emap.com.ar/css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://emap.com.ar/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://emap.com.ar/plugins/chosen/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://emap.com.ar/plugins/sceditor/themes/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://emap.com.ar/plugins/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://emap.com.ar/css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

---

Por otro lado, PSR-2 es el estilo de código de PHP, el cual te recomiendo que lo utilices en tu proyecto, pero no tiene nada que ver con el código HTML.

Aquí está la documentación de PSR-2: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: Funciona seleccionando el codigo previamente. Y al tener bien divido con section e include es bastante sencillo formatear codigo php